# In case of concurrency and no multi-processing, in what order is code executed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency

I'm building an application using Node and I was wondering the following. I know that nodejs is concurrent but not multiprocessing. If I have a callback which should be executed while other code is executed, does it simply pause the other code to execute the callback?

Considering the following code:

```
function mycallback(data) {
    // some code
}

function_which_takes_a_callback(mycallback);

for (let i = 0; i < 9999999999; i++) {
    // do something else
}
```

If the callback comes back while the for-loop is still running, does it simply stop the execution of the loop and the code within it to execute the `mycallback()` function and then proceed with the loop? Or does it finish the loop? Or yet something else?

And is the way `nodejs` handles this different from other concurrent but non-multiprocessing languages (no idea which other languages but I presume there are other ones)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the callback comes back while the for-loop is still running, does it simply stop the execution of the loop and the code within it to execute the `mycallback()` function and then proceed with the loop?

No, the loop ends first and at some point later (or never) the callback will be fired. Synchronous code is never interrupted in JS by other JS code (it can be interrupted by OS though). The internal context switch (i.e. jump to callback) can only occure when there is no synchronous code running at the moment.

> And is the way `nodejs` handles this different from other concurrent but non-multiprocessing languages (no idea which other languages but I presume there are other ones)?

To put it simply: other languages that can spawn threads can run multiple synchronous codes concurrently. Languages that cannot spawn threads can't do that. Usually every code you run (no matter what language you use) can be (and often is) interrupted by OS. The OS won't let you take 100% cpu time for yourself, no sir. But single threaded VMs (e.g. JS) are not capabale of taking advantage of that. Once OS gives control back to JS it resumes where it stoped. That's a simple consequence of JS being single-threaded (which isn't 100% true, but for the simplicity I assume JS is single-threaded).

In other words, from the dev's perspective, synchronous JS code cannot be interrupted by any internal event. I also encourage you to test it. For example schedule `setTimeout` and make a busy loop checking time:

```
function busy(timeout) {
    var n = Date.now();
    var end = n + timeout;
    while (n < end)
        n = Date.now();
}
setTimeout(function() { console.log('test'); }, 1000);
busy(3000);
```

and observe that the console prints `test` after 3s, not 1s as scheduled.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I didn't know that synchronous code can never be interrupted by async code. That immediately gives me a different perspective. My code is filled with callbacks. It calls multiple APIs, receives constant events on a websocket which it stores in the DB and on which it needs to act with rather heavy calculations and other api calls. I haven't done any profiling yet but if it maxes out the cpu I guess I may be in trouble. Is the reverse also true; if I don't have 100% CPU usage can I be (relatively) sure that callback code is started in a timely manner (within a second or so)?

Comment: @kramer65 Profiling is always the best idea in this situation. But yes, if you don't utilize 100% cpu you should be ok. Typically JS scheduler lag is around ~1-2 millis (which human mind doesn't even perceive as time flow) in that scenario. And yes, if you do heavy synchronous calculations then you block everything else. But you can try utilizing other CPU cores via subprocessing for example.

Comment: @kramer65 Also note that you can divide your synchronous code into multiple small pieces and run them concurrently via [process.nextTick](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_args). Not necessarly in parallel but sequentially. This will allow you to do small chunks of calculations each time while not blocking whole process. Allowing other things to run, i.e. you gain responsivness. But as usual: profile before you go down that road.

Comment: Thanks for your last tip! One last question; what do you mean with `(or never)`, could it be that a callback is never executed? Do you mean in case the program uses 100% cpu for the rest of our lifetime or in case the program ends in an error before the callback could be executed? Or do you hint at some other situation?

Comment: @kramer65 Depending on what the asynchronous code does it is possible that the synchronous code will just "deactivate" it. Consider my example with `setTimeout` and then `clearTimeout` at the end of the loop. In that case the callback never runs. It's a pathological case but still possible. Other then that there are scenarios like: the process simply crashes because it runs out of memory (or because of some bug in some lib or JS itself). Or it is killed by OS. Possibly other cases. But yeah, typically the callback should run at some point.

Comment: @kramer65 And last but not least: `process.nextTick` can be abused to insert a callback before anything else fires. Like `function insert() { process.nextTick(insert); }; insert();`. It isn't synchronous but it is similar to an infinite while loop. (Almost) Nothing else can run. Congrats, you've just destroyed your own app. :) I'm telling you about it so you are careful with `process.nextTick` in case you want to use it.

Comment: considering `function_which_takes_a_callback` is an actual async method, which takes a callback, not just a sync function which takes a callback. If it's a sync function, it will execute even before the loop. I just had a debate with one the çandidate I was interviewing.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (let i = 0; i < 9999999999; i++) {
    // some blocking stuff
    // some non-blocking stuff
}
```

by *blocking*, it means a synchronous code execution which is being executed by system and cannot be interrupted. Consider image resize call there or may be a doc-to-pdf conversion which is implemented to happen synchronously.

by *non-blocking*, it means a code which executes some portion and may wait for some event in future or some I/O (write-to-disk?, user-input(gets), or network(xhr?)), when such calls are executed, they run their partial code and register themselves in a queue from where they can resume once the pending thing is done.

Now, what happens if following code is executed (added line numbers for reference):

```
1. function mycallback(data) {
2.     // some code
3. }

4. function_which_takes_a_callback(mycallback);

5. for (let i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
6.         // some blocking stuff(for example 1s)
7.         // some non-blocking stuff
8. }
```

from line 1-3, a function `mycallback` is registered.
at line 4, a function_which_takes_a_callback is executed and mycallback is passed, it does some work and may invoke mycallback once done
at line 5-8, for 999 times, the thread will block for atleast 999 times till `mycallback` is executed.

Only after that code is done with it's execution will it free up the stack, prompting event loop to check from the event queue which can be processed.

Try this out:

```js
function syncCode() {
    var fromTime = Date.now();
    var toTime = Date.now() + 1000;
    while (fromTime < toTime) {
        fromTime = Date.now();
    }
}
function asyncCode() {
    console.log(new Date(), "Invoked asyncCode");
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(new Date(), "async code should have come 1s after Start");
    }, 1000);
}
console.log(new Date(), "Start");
asyncCode();

console.log("Sync code repeatedly for 10s");
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    syncCode();
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(new Date(), "sync code should be coming after async code callback");
    }, 1000)
}
console.log(new Date(), "End");
```